# find the number whose occurring times are over N/3

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers

There is a random array whose size is N， find the number whose occurring times are over N/3？
for example：

```
{1,2,14,12,12,15,12,12,8} the result is 12
```

who has more effective algorithm？
I do it like this：

```
int getNum(int *arr, int left, int right, const int size)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int index = rand()%(right - left + 1) + left;
    std::swap(arr[left], arr[index]);
    int flag = arr[left];
    int small = left;
    int big = right;
    int equal = left;
    while(equal <= big)
    {
        if(arr[equal] == flag)
        {
            equal++;
        }
        else if(arr[equal] < flag)
        {
            swap(arr[equal++], arr[small++]);
        }
        else
        {
            while(big > equal && arr[big] > flag)
            {
                big--;
            }
            std::swap(arr[big], arr[equal]);
            big--;
        }
    }
    if(equal - small >= (size / 3))
    {
        return arr[small];
    }
    if(small - left >= size/3)
    {
        return getNum(arr, left, small - 1, size);
    }
    if(right - equal + 1 >= size/3)
    {
        return getNum(arr, equal, right, size);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

first, I define three flags small equal and big, select one number as the flag,and find the 
right range of this number,when `equal - small > size / 3`, this is the very number that we find, else find the side whose size over `size / 3` and recursion!

Comment: The problem is not well specified. Do you need every number that occurs more than N/3 times? Do you just pick the most often occurring number? What if there are no numbers that occur that often? What is the expected range of the input numbers?

Comment: input numbers are random,yes you are right maybe there are more than one numbers fit the request but no more then three,I just want to one of these number

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining if an array has a k-majority element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116788/determining-if-an-array-has-a-k-majority-element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually - [there is an algorithm proposed by Karp-Papadimitriou-Shanker](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/datamining2011aFiles/ASimpleAlgorithmForFindingFrequentElementsInStreamsAndBags.pdf) to find items that appears `1/k` times in the data with a single pass. Of course it can be applied for `k=3`.

The algorithm however gives *false positives* (says something is frequent though it is not) - but using a 2nd pass on the data with the given 3 candidates, these can be easily eliminated.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
PF = {}
for each element e:
  if pf.containsKey(e): 
     pf.put(e, pf.get(e)+1) //increase the value by 1
  else:
     pf.put(e,1)
     if pf.size() == k:
         for each key in pf:
              pf.put(key, pf.get(key)-1) //decrease all elements by 1
              if pf.get(key) == 0: //remove elements with value 0
                 pf.remove(key)
output pf
```

more info and proof on the above algorithm can be found in [this page](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236620/Spring2013/ho/WCFiles/Lec10-steaming.pdf), slides 8-12

Even with a second pass, the complexity of the algorithm is `O(n)` time with `O(k)` (in your case `k==3`) extra space.

Comment: can you extract the time complexity to us here?

Comment: @sasha.sochka just did. It's O(n) time complexity with O(k) (k==3 in this case) extra space.

Comment: there is a problem in your code:which data structure does pf use,and the time complexity of pf.containsKey(e)?

Comment: @minicaptain It can be a hash table - and then it will be `O(n)` average case and `O(nk)` worst case in your case k=3, so it is still `O(n)` - or it can be a balanced BST with `O(nlogK)` worst and average case.

Answer (score 1):

Another (probabilistic) algorithm - choose, say 50 random values in the array.

Choose the value which occurred the most in this array and check if it fits you criteria in the original array (This operation is `O(1)` because 50 is a constant). It will work from the first time with 99% chance. But if it fails - get the second value from the small (50 elements) array and try it. Continue this way. The overall complexity is `O(n)` but this approach requires modification if it's possible that there is no value which fits the criteria in the original array.

Comment: If you have something to add to your answer, edit it., tell me  which is correct?? which is to vote??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, these answers are completely disconnected. And I've seen similar splitting of answers on SO already.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, vote for the answer you agree with. If you like both - vote for both. If you don't like neither of them - don't vote at all.

Comment: The problem with this approach is nothing ensures you the element that repeats 1/3 times is indeed in the smaller array - you will have to resample it each iteration (and not as you propose).

Comment: In addition - when to stop? If you found an element that repeats 1/3 times, it does not mean there is no second (or 3rd item) as well.

Comment: @amit, author didn't specify our behaviour. Still we can modify this approach - try a couple of next values in the small array. If you make this small array  with size = 100 or even bigger you can get probability very close to 100% but, comparative to your answer, it's going to be both slower and not determined, at least in theory. If there is no such an element - you can stop after say 10 or 20 tries.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to sort the elements and if the element at index i+N/3-1 is equal to the element at index i, then this element appears at least N/3 times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compar(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int*)a) - (*(int*)b);
}

int main() {
    int N = 9;
    int N3 = N / 3;
    int tab[] = {1,2,14,12,12,15,12,12,8};

    qsort(tab, N, sizeof(int), compar);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= N - N3; i++) {
        if (tab[i] == tab[i+N3-1]) {
            printf("%d\n", tab[i]);
        }
        while (tab[i] == tab[i+N3-1]) {
            i += N3 - 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The complexity is O(n log n) (because of the sort). If the table is already sorted, it's linear.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt to solve this problem is to use HashMap. The code went as follows:

```
public int O_N_Memory_Solution(final List<Integer> a){
    int repetationCount = a.size()/3;
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++){
        if(map.containsKey(a.get(i)))   map.put(a.get(i),map.get(a.get(i))+1);
        else    map.put(a.get(i),1);
        if(map.get(a.get(i))>repetationCount) return a.get(i);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It's a small code right, but consume more memory and time.

I didn't know there is an algorithm for this problem, here is my implementation for ***Karp-Papadimitriou-Shanker Algorithm***.

The main idea of the algorithm is to notice that **the removal of K distinct elements from the array will not change the answer**.

K here is equal to 3, and we are trying to find any element with more than n/3 occurrences in the array.

```
// Karp-Papadimitriou-Shenker Algorithm
public int O_1_Memory_Solution(final List<Integer> a){
    if(a.size() == 0) return -1;

    int firstInt = 0, secondInt = 0;
    int firstCount = 0;
    int secondCount = 0;
    int current;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){

        current = a.get(i);

        // You should check 1st before setting so that, if one of the two integers is empty, 
        // you increment the non empty integer if the current matches it, not adding the current to
        // the empty one.

        if(current == firstInt && firstCount!=0) {
            firstCount++;
        } else if(current == secondInt && secondCount!=0) {
            secondCount++;
        } else if(firstCount == 0) {
            firstInt = current;
            firstCount = 1;
        } else if(secondCount == 0) {
            secondInt = current;
            secondCount = 1;
        } else {
            firstCount--;
            secondCount--;
        }

    }

    int repetationCount = a.size()/3;
    int[] candidates = {firstInt,secondInt};
    int ac;
    /* Check actual counts of potential candidates */
    for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
        // Calculate actual count of elements 
        ac = 0;  // actual count
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)
            if (a.get(j) == candidates[i])
                ac++;

        // If actual count is more than n/k, then print it
        if (ac > repetationCount) return candidates[i];
    }

    return -1;
}
```