# Find all elements that appear more than n/4 times in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

This problem is 4-11 of Skiena. The solution to finding majority elements - repeated more than half times is majority algorithm. Can we use this to find all numbers repeated n/4 times?

Comment: The exercise probably asks to use the idea of the approach for n/2, not the algorithm as a subroutine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find if there is an element repeating itself n/k times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001181/find-if-there-is-an-element-repeating-itself-n-k-times)

Answer (score 5):

[Misra and Gries](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/misra/scannedPdf.dir/FindRepeatedElements.pdf) describe a couple approaches. I don't entirely understand their paper, but a key idea is to *use a bag*.

[Boyer and Moore's original majority algorithm paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Emoore/best-ideas/mjrty/) has a lot of incomprehensible proofs and discussion of formal verification of FORTRAN code, but it has a very good *start* of an explanation of how the majority algorithm works. The key concept starts with the idea that if the majority of the elements are `A` and you remove, one at a time, a copy of `A` and a copy of something else, then in the end you will have only copies of `A`. Next, it should be clear that removing two different items, neither of which is `A`, can only increase the majority that `A` holds. Therefore it's safe to remove *any* pair of items, as long as they're different. This idea can then be made concrete. Take the first item out of the list and stick it in a box. Take the next item out and stick it in the box. If they're the same, let them both sit there. If the new one is *different*, throw it away, along with an item from the box. Repeat until all items are either in the box or in the trash. Since the box is only allowed to have one kind of item at a time, it can be represented very efficiently as a pair `(item type, count)`.

The generalization to find all items that may occur more than `n/k` times is simple, but explaining why it works is a little harder. The basic idea is that we can find and destroy groups of `k` *distinct* elements without changing anything. Why? If `w > n/k` then `w-1 > (n-k)/k`. That is, if we take away one of the popular elements, and we also take away `k-1` *other* elements, then the popular element remains popular!

Implementation: instead of only allowing *one* kind of item in the box, allow `k-1` of them. Whenever you see a group of `k` *different* items show up (that is, there are `k-1` types in the box, and the one arriving doesn't match any of them), you throw one of each type in the trash, including the one that just arrived. What data structure should we use for this "box"? Well, a bag, of course! As Misra and Gries explain, if the elements can be ordered, a tree-based bag with O(log k) basic operations will give the whole algorithm a complexity of O(n log k). One point to note is that the operation of removing one of each element is a bit expensive (O(k) for a typical implementation), but that cost is amortized over the arrivals of those elements, so it's no big deal. Of course, if your elements are hashable rather than orderable, you can use a hash-based bag instead, which under certain common assumptions will give even better asymptotic performance (but it's not guaranteed). If your elements are drawn from a small finite set, you can guarantee that. If they can only be compared for *equality*, then your bag gets much more expensive and I'm pretty sure you end up with something like O(nk) instead.

Answer (score 2):

See [this paper](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/datamining2011aFiles/ASimpleAlgorithmForFindingFrequentElementsInStreamsAndBags.pdf) for a solution that uses constant memory and runs in linear time, which will find 3 candidates for elements that occur more than n/4 times. Note that if you assume that your data is given as a stream that you can only go through once, this is the best you can do -- you have to go through the stream one more time to test each of the 3 candidates to see if it occurs more than n/4 times in the stream. However, if you assume a priori that there are 3 elements that occur more than n/4 times then you only need to go through the stream once so you get a linear time online algorithm (only goes through the stream once) that only requires constant storage.

Answer (score 2):

Find the majority element that appears `n/2 times` by **Moore-Voting Algorithm**

See method 3 of the given link for Moore's Voting Algo (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/).

**Time:O(n)**

Now after finding majority element, scan the array again and `remove the majority element` or make it `-1.`

**Time:O(n)**

Now apply Moore Voting Algorithm on the remaining elements of array (but ignore -1 now as it has already been included earlier). The new majority element appears `n/4 times.`

**Time:O(n)**

**Total Time:O(n)**

**Extra Space:O(1)**

You can do it for element appearing more than n/8,n/16,.... times

**EDIT:**

There may exist a case when there is no majority element in the array:

For e.g. if the input arrays is `{3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3}` then the output should be `[2, 3]`.

**Given an array of of size n and a number k, find all elements that appear more than n/k times**

See this link for the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24642388/3714537

References:

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/

Comment: What if the most common element isn't in the majority?  For example, if 1, 2, and 3 each occur n/3 times.

Comment: The method 3 of above link checks if the majority element exists after finding a potential majority element.

Comment: But if there is no majority element, the method can give you pretty much anything.

Comment: The note at the end of that paper mentions a later one (which was actually *published* years earlier, for stupid reasons) that is much better than what you suggest. See http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/misra/scannedPdf.dir/FindRepeatedElements.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As you didnt mention space complexity , one possible solution is using [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for the elements which maps to count then you can just increment count if the element is found.