# Find all elements that appear more than n/4 times in a sorted array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, python-3.x, refactoring

My question is similar to [Find all elements that appear more than n/4 times in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691048/find-all-elements-that-appear-more-than-n-4-times-in-linear-time), you are given an array of size n, find all elements that appear more than n/4 times, the difference is that the array is sorted and the runtime should be better than O(n).

My approach is to do 3 binary searches for the first occurrence of each element in position n/4, n/2 and 3*n/4, since the array is sorted, we can know if each element appears more than n/4 times by checking if the next n/4 element has the same value.

I have written the following code in python3, do you guys think my approach is correct and if there is anything that can be simplified?:

```
import bisect

# return -1 if x doesn't exist in arr
def binary_search(arr, x):
    pos = bisect.bisect_left(arr, x)
    return pos if pos != len(arr) and arr[pos] == x else -1

def majority(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    output = []
    quarters = [arr[n//4],arr[n//2],arr[3*n//4]]

    # avoid repeating answer in output array
    if arr[n//4] == arr[n//2]:
        quarters.remove(arr[n//4])
        quarters.remove(arr[n//2])
        output.append(arr[n//2])
    if arr[n//2] == arr[3*n//4]:
        if arr[n//2] in arr:
            quarters.remove(quarters[n//2])
        if arr[3*n//4] in arr:
            quarters.remove(quarters[3*n//4])
        if arr[n//2] not in output:
            output.append(arr[n//2])

    for quarter in quarters:
        pos = binary_search(arr, quarter)
        if pos != -1 and pos+n//4 < len(arr) and arr[pos] == arr[pos+n//4]:
            output.append(arr[pos])
    return output

print(majority([1,1,1,6,6,6,9,145]))
```

Comment: I think avoid repeating the answer makes it way harder. You are correct that if an element occurs 1/4th or more of the time, it occurs at least once in the `quarter`. But your approach of removing is wrong. Since if `arr[n//4] == arr[n//2]`, then you remove both, but now there is a change that you removed all occurences.

Comment: NlogN is not better than O(N)

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: but the list is sorted as a precondition.

Comment: The approach you describe doesn't sound right. For example, if an item occurs (n/4)+1 times, it could start at, say, position 2 and end at position (n/4)+2. That element would appear in position (n/4), but not in position 0 or (n/2). If your code implements what you described, then it's wrong. If your code works, then it doesn't implement what you described.

Comment: @JimMischel: Do you have an example input for this? If array[n/4] == 1, my algorithm would find first occurrence of 1, let's say it's at 2, then it would check if array[2+n/4] == array[2] to verify if it appears more than n/4 times.

Comment: Based on your clarification, I suspect your approach is correct. The point of my comment is that your description is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is more like:

```
Examine the element at position n/4
Do a binary search to find the first occurrence of that item.
Do a binary search to find the next occurrence of that item.
If last-first > n/4, then output it.

Repeat that process for n/2 and 3(n/4)
```

There is an early out opportunity if the previous item extends beyond the next n/4 marker.

Comment: after finding the first occurrence, there is no need to binary search on next occurrence of that item. just check first_occur_pos + n/4 to see if it is the same number.

Answer (score -2):

I would make the following improvement.  Take the 9 values that are at position 0, n/8, n/4, 3n/8, ..., n.  You only need to consider values that were repeated twice.

When you do the binary search, you can do both ends in tandem.  That way if the most common value is much smaller or much larger than 1/4 then you don't do most of the binary search.

Comment: But for the list `[1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, `1` is not repeated *more* than 1/4th (2 times).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No problem, it would show up as a candidate in the 8'ths pass, and then fail the binary search.  The point is that an `O(1)` check can usually eliminate the `O(log(n))` search.  And the `O(log(n))` search can usually be short-circuited when you do do it.